Clarifications on Hurst Exponent Definitions and Persistence Properties
I have a question regarding the Hurst exponent that I hope someone here can help clarify.
It is well known that there are different definitions of the Hurst exponent, but finding clear connections or relationships between these definitions seems to be surprisingly challenging. I’ve come across various interpretations, yet I haven’t found a comprehensive explanation of how these different definitions align or differ in practical applications.
Additionally, it is commonly stated that:

For $H<0.5$ the process exhibits antipersistence.
For $H>0.5$ the process exhibits persistence.

However, while this classification appears frequently, the reasoning or deeper explanation behind it is rarely provided.
Could anyone offer some clarifications, or perhaps point me toward reliable bibliographic references that address:

The relationships between the various definitions of the Hurst exponent.
A clear explanation of why $H<0.5$ corresponds to antipersistence and $H>0.5$ corresponds to persistence.

For example :
Let's take the $R/S$ analysis, for me it is more defined as a procedure wich has an output H :
Given a sequence $\left(X_i\right)_{i\in\{1,\dots,N\}}$. Divided into subsequences of lenght $n$
For all subsequence $X_1,\dots, X_n$

Compute the mean: $m = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$
Compute mean-adjusted serie: $Y_t = X_t - m,\quad t=1,\dots,n$
Cumulative deviate series: $ Z_t = \sum_{i=1}^{t} Y_i, \quad t=1,\dots,n$
Range: $R(n) = \max_{1 \leq t \leq n} Z_t \;-\; \min_{1 \leq t \leq n} Z_t$
Standard deviation : $S(n) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - m)^2}$
Rescaled range: $\frac{R(n)}{S(n)}$
Compute the mean of all $R(n)/S(n)$, which we denote $E\left(R(n)/S(n)\right)$ (not the proper expectation, it is just a notation).
The compute an $H$ such as $E\left(R(n)/S(n)\right)\propto n^H$ which can be donne by a linear regression (taking the $\log$ on both sides) or the maximum-likelihood

On other hand there is the fBM
Fractional Brownian motion is a continuous-time Gaussian process $B_H(t)$ defined on the interval $[0,T]$. It starts at zero, has zero expectation for all $t \in [0,T]$, and has the following covariance function:
$$E[B_H(t)B_H(s)] = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(|t|^{2H} + |s|^{2H} - |t - s|^{2H}\bigr)$$
where $H \in (0,1)$ is called the Hurst index.
In the book of Selected aspects of fBM by Ivan Nourdin it is proved that if we compute the $R/S$ on a fBM with Hurst index $H$, the theoretic return value is indeed $H$.

Could you cite some of these different definitions, so we don't have to look them up and guess what you are referring to?

At least I found 5 : R/S Analysis (Rescaled Range); Self-Similarity (Scaling); Covariance-Based (for Gaussian Self-Similar Processes); Path Regularity (Hölder Continuity); Variance Scaling Definition.

Good: now we have some names for them.  But what are these various definitions?

Please add new info as an edit to the post, not only as a comment. Comments on this site are often seen only by a few, and can be deleted.  Also, you can search this site  for  hurst  and long-range-dependence

In particular, it's unclear whether you are referring to definitions or to estimators.
